# What does "gern" stands for and how to use it?

Tags: translation, german-to-english, adverb

I have some issue understanding **gern** in the following context:

> Anna und ich trinken gern ein Glas Wein.

Does it mean:

- "We enjoy a glass of wine" ("*Nous aimons un verre de vin*") as Linguee in French suggested to me
- "We would enjoy a glass of wine" ("*Nous aimerions un verre de vin*") as Linguee in English suggested to me

Answer (score 5):

Actually the context is a bit slim for a substantial answer.

As answer to a question like: "What would you like to drink, orange juice, beer or a glas of wine?" *gern(e)* (not meant as one-word answer but e.g. within "Ich nehme gern einen Wein") simply states preference for the latter with conotation of some politeness. (This seems the meaning @Twinfriends addressed, but is far from being the only one.)

As a stand-alone statement it could express a habit, similar to

> Ich mache abends gern einen Spaziergang.  (I like to take a walk in the evening)

(obviously one also has to like doing this, otherwise one would not do it so often) or, more similar to you example and also more tending towards peference

> Ich trinke gern einen Wein zum Fisch.

I like to drink a glas of wine, when having a fish.

Comment: Huh? The question gives a very specific context and part of your answer addresses something which doesn't refer to that context. And "gern" is a terrible answer to a question like "what whould you like to drink: a, b, c?"

Comment: @Em1: I fail to see how two French sentences with an assumed content of "We like wine" establishes a context. The second part seems to originate in some misunderstanding; I tried to clarify the answer via edit.

Answer (score 4):

> Anna und ich trinken gern ein Glas Wein.

Actually, none of the more literal translations 100% hits the German meaning that conveys "enjoyment every now and then". We are not talking about the action of drinking, but rather the habit of enjoying.

I would translate to

> Anna and I tend to enjoy a glass of wine.

or, more literally

> Anna and I like to drink a glass of wine [every now and then].

Comment: Great answer. "Anna and I like to drink" is spot on. You can also use "enjoy" without "tend to". "We enjoy drinking a glass of wine" means that we get pleasure from doing that.

Comment: @Em1 I was thinking about "...enjoy drinking a glass..." but then decided to very bluntly express the *habit* undertone, which is present in your proposal, but might or might not be obvious depending on he reader's command of English.

Answer (score 1):

First example is correct.
Second one would be:

> Anna und ich **würden** gern ein Glas Wein trinken.

Comment: While formatting your answer, I incidentally removed the "e" in "gerne". I did this merely to maintain the form that was used in the question.

Answer (score -1):

It means “Anna and I like to drink a glas of wine”.

I can think of two different meanings though. See:

> Case A: You and Anna are the guests of (Insert host here).
> Host: Hello, do you want to drink Cola or some Wine?
> [English] Me: Anna and I would like to drink a glass of wine.
> [German]  Ich: Anna und Ich trinken gern ein Glas Wein.
>
> Case B: You get asked whether you like wine or not.
> Reporter: Hello, just a quick question, do you drink wine sometimes or not at >all?
> [English] Me: Anna and I enjoy to drink a glass of wine, every now and then.
> [German]  Ich: Anna und ich trinken (ab und zu) gern ein Glas Wein.

*ab und zu = every now and then*, similar to *sometimes*.